# Enabling GDA2020 in Global Mapper

Tags: coordinate-system, global-mapper, gda2020

Enabling Australia's GDA2020 datum in Global Mapper has been discussed in a Global Mapper Forum thread titled [Australian GDA2020 implementation issue](https://www.globalmapperforum.com/discussion/16537/australian-gda2020-implementation-issue).  That discussion seems to say that GDA2020 can be enabled in Global Mapper versions after 23.1.

I am using Global Mapper 18.2.0 and I have a Global Mapper Map Catalog of JPEG2000 images in GDA2020.  Those images were projected from GDA94 using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.  In order to export that Map Catalog into an ECW image to that retains GDA2020 georeferencing I need first to configure a suitable projection for the export.

When I try to do that, I am offered GDA94 as a choice but not GDA2020.

[image]

If it is possible to enable GDA2020 support in Global Mapper 18.2.0, then how do I do it?

I suspect that a later version may be needed, but I am new to Global Mapper and unsure of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

18.2.0 is a little dated (2017/2018) in the 22.1 (2021) I see it available.

[image]

I would speak to support at Blue Marble.
https://www.bluemarblegeo.com/technical-support/

*(the cost is not huge to be on the maintenance plan)*